# Is it mandatory to use ViewModel and Live Data Classes in MVVM Pattern in Android? Else can we use MVVM pattern without using them?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm trying to implement MVVM pattern in my existing project. I have confusion on that lot of developer sites and tutorials i have read but everywhere MVVM pattern using with live data and view model only. Like is there any possibility without using LiveData and ViewModel can we use MVVM pattern

**Question 1**.without using LiveData and ViewModel can we use MVVM pattern android? 
**Question 2**.without using LiveData what is the use of extending ViewModel to some class (like class Test extends ViewModel)

I'm doing RecyclerView pagination to get set of records each and every time once scroll ends like below

```
 ProfileListViewModel viewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileListViewModel.class);


//to get first set of records
   viewModel.getProfileList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Profiles>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Profiles> profiles) {
                if (projects != null) {
                    //…
                    profileAdapter.setProfiles(profiles);
                }
            }
        });





//to get second set of records

   viewModel.getRemaningProfileList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Profiles>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Profiles> profiles) {
                if (projects != null) {
                    //…
                    profileAdapter.setProfiles(profiles);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Question 3** : for this feature using MVVM do we need to use two method calls(two LiveData objects) like above for getting new records every time else is there any alternative.its so confusing me.

**Question 4** :   sometimes I will insert some records in SQLite android that time again I'm calling this method from start like (viewModel.getProfileList().observe())...after that '

I'm clearing current LiveData and setting again new records..is there any possibilities are like once record inserted/update it will refresh data automatically.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Ans 1. You can use MVVM patern without using LiveData but ViewModel is compulosry as without using it, MVVM would be meaningless. LiveData is used to observe the changes at activity/fragment made on a variable/method inside view model.

Ans 2. View Model is used to to prepare and manage the data for Activity/Fragment. The call to API and other business logics are written in class extending view model. This is done to achieve Separation of Code.

Ans 3. if viewModel.getProfileList() is getting you the list of records, you don't need to use  viewModel.getRemaningProfileList() to get the same data. Changes at viewModel.getProfileList() will be observed and inflated every time there is change in data.

Ans 4. You can use Activity/Frament's life cycle methods to receive the data automatically. For eg, in an activity,

```
onCreate(){
   ProfileListViewModel viewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileListViewModel.class);

}
onStart(){
     getObservedData();
}
private void getObservedData(){
viewModel.getProfileList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Profiles>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Profiles> profiles) {
            if (projects != null) {
                //…
                profileAdapter.setProfiles(profiles);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Like said MVVM stands for Model - View - View Model

Comment: For your third answer i have one doubt..first we will get set of 30 records..in getProfileList.observe method we will receive data and we set to arraylist inside adapter..

let's say now adapter arraylist have 30 records as well as livedata have 30 records

then second call for remaining 30 records this time live data already have 30 records and if we set remaining 30 records to same live data..then onChange livedata will give 60 records now..then if i set those 60 records to arraylist inside adapter then it will be 90 records right with duplicate records..how we can avoid this.
Thanks

Comment: @TirupatiraoV to avoid duplication of data, you have to create a method in adapter which clears your list. Every time you call your API, before inflating data in an adapter, first you call the clear method, and then set the new data.